# Pandas Split features tuples

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a problem with a feature in my DataFrame. This is my DataFrame (just the feature that i want to use):

```
0     (a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)
1     (a,1.0),(b,6.0)
2     (a,1.0),(x,6.0),(e,5)
```

I would like to create a feature with the string which have the bigger weight.
Example (after the script) I would like a new feature:

```
0 c
1 b
2 x
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Counter` and [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), but my format of input is a bit different - it is `list` of `tuples`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[('a',1.0),('b',6.0),('c',10.0)],
                        [('a',1.0),('b',6.0) ],
                        [('a',1.0),('x',6.0),('e',5)]]})
print (df)
                                 a
0  [(a, 1.0), (b, 6.0), (c, 10.0)]
1             [(a, 1.0), (b, 6.0)]
2     [(a, 1.0), (x, 6.0), (e, 5)]

print (df.a.apply(lambda x: Counter(dict(x)).most_common(1)[0][0]))
0    c
1    b
2    x
Name: a, dtype: object
```

It was not easy and I have to ask [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42136984/2901002).

You need:

```
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)']]})

print (df)
                            a
0  [(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)]

df.a = df.a.str[0].str.replace(r'\((\w+),', r"('\1',").apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
print (df)
                                 a
0  ((a, 1.0), (b, 6.0), (c, 10.0))

print (df.a.apply(lambda x: Counter(dict(x)).most_common(1)[0][0]))
0    c
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. My df is the same thing that: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)']]})`

Comment: Phooo, it is very complicated. Main problem is same separator `,` between `tuples` and between `values`

Comment: OK now we change the format: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['(a,1.0):(b,6.0):(c,10.0)']]})`

Comment: Try change `\((\w+),'` to `\((\w+):'`