# Convert string tuples to dict

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, replace

I have malformed string:

```
a = '(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)'
```

I need `dict`:

```
d = {'a':1.0, 'b':6.0, 'c':10.0}
```

I try:

```
print (ast.literal_eval(a))
#ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000000000F67E828>
```

Then I try replace chars to `'string dict'`, it is ugly and does not work:

```
b = a.replace(',(','|{').replace(',',' : ')
     .replace('|',', ').replace('(','{').replace(')','}')
print (b)
{a : 1.0}, {b : 6.0}, {c : 10.0}

print (ast.literal_eval(b))
#ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000000000C2EA588>
```

What do you do? Something missing? Is possible use `regex`?

Comment: Well the string is mallformed because the first element of each tuple is not a char, but an `a` (so an identifier).

Comment: Yes, it is main problem I think.

Comment: will the given string always have the above format? One can indeed fix the string with a regex, but regex substitutions are a bit dangerous if the input format is unspecified.

Comment: I think and I hope yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the string has the above stated format, you could use regex substitution with *backrefs*:

```
import re

a = '(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)'
a_fix = re.sub(r'\((\w+),', r"('\1',",a)
```

So you look for a pattern `(x,` (with `x` a sequence of `\w`s and you substitute it into `('x',`. The result is then:

```
# result
a_fix == "('a',1.0),('b',6.0),('c',10.0)"
```

and then parse `a_fix` and convert it to a `dict`:

```
result = dict(ast.literal_eval(a_fix))
```

The result in then:

```
>>> dict(ast.literal_eval(a_fix))
{'b': 6.0, 'c': 10.0, 'a': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for regexes, if your string is in this format.

```
>>> a = '(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)'
>>> d = dict([x.split(',') for x in a[1:-1].split('),(')])
>>> print(d)
{'c': '10.0', 'a': '1.0', 'b': '6.0'}
```

We remove the first opening parantheses and last closing parantheses to get the key-value pairs by splitting on `),(`. The pairs can then be split on the comma.

To cast to float, the list comprehension gets a little longer:

```
d = dict([(a, float(b)) for (a, b) in [x.split(',') for x in a[1:-1].split('),(')]])
```

Comment: Sure, added it in my answer. Nested list comprehensions ftw!

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately I cannot implemented in pandas, so I accept another answer.

Answer (score 3):

If there are always 2 comma-separated values inside parentheses and the second is of a float type, you may use

```
import re
s = '(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)'
print(dict(map(lambda (w, m): (w, float(m)), [(x, y) for x, y in re.findall(r'\(([^),]+),([^)]*)\)', s) ])))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FRHdtp) and the (quite generic) [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GLUuDX/1). This pattern just matches a `(`, then 0+ chars other than a comma and `)` capturing into Group 1, then a comma is matched, then any 0+ chars other than `)` (captured into Group 2) and a `)`.

As the pattern above is suitable when you have pre-validated data, the regex can  be restricted for your current data as

```
r'\((\w+),(\d*\.?\d+)\)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nKuboW/1)

**Details**:

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word (letter/digit/`_`) chars
- `,` - a comma
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - a common integer/float regex: zero or more digits, an optional `.` (decimal separator) and 1+ digits
- `\)` - a literal closing parenthesis.

Comment: You can (in fact, I think you should) avoid using regexes

Comment: @BlackBear: If validation is necessary, then a regex will be an advantage,  I am adding details now.

Answer (score 3):

the reason why `eval()` dose not work is the `a, b, c` are not defined, we can define those with it's string form and eval will get that string form to use

```
In [11]: text = '(a,1.0),(b,6.0),(c,10.0)'

In [12]: a, b, c = 'a', 'b', 'c'

In [13]: eval(text)
Out[13]: (('a', 1.0), ('b', 6.0), ('c', 10.0))

In [14]: dict(eval(text))
Out[14]: {'a': 1.0, 'b': 6.0, 'c': 10.0}
```

to do this in regex way:

```
In [21]: re.sub(r'\((.+?),', r'("\1",', text)
Out[21]: '("a",1.0),("b",6.0),("c",10.0)'
In [22]: eval(_)
Out[22]: (('a', 1.0), ('b', 6.0), ('c', 10.0))

In [23]: dict(_)
Out[23]: {'a': 1.0, 'b': 6.0, 'c': 10.0}
```

Comment: First of all **`eval`** is considered **very dangerous** (since a hacker could introduce arbitrary code, notice that the OP uses `literal_eval` which is something else). Next in general the OP does not know what the keys will be, and finally, here you assign a lot of values to variables (that you perhaps would like to use for something else)...